# How to fix engine "node" version?

Tags: node.js

How to fix it?

[2/4] Fetching packages...
Error nes.css@2.3.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this
module. Expected version "10.x". Got "14.15.4"
error found incompatible module.

Comment: You need lower your version. Either you need to delete it and install version 10 or you can start to use `nvm`

Comment: Or switch to an NPM package that is compatible with newer versions of nodejs.  Or inquire with the author of the module in question about its compatibility with node 14.15.4.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed with  yarn install --ignore-engines