# The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "7.5.0". Got "15.13.0"

Tags: node.js, reactjs

one of my friends sent me a project using react and node and i tried to run it with yarn. Each time i run this command i got this error : The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "7.5.0". Got "15.13.0". I just want to know how update the react version of a project

Have a good day

Comment: Node v7.5.0 hasn't been in use since 2017-01-31. Updating dependencies will most likely cause breaking changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your package.json

```
 "engines": { "node": ">=7.5.0"},
```

This will make the projects run with node 7.5.0 or newer versions. Also using nvm

```
nvm install version_you_want 
nvm use version_you_want
```

Check node and npm versions

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Other option is to use

yarn install --ignore-engines

See this post: [How to fix engine "node" version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67574784/how-to-fix-engine-node-version)

In my case I was gettin the same error because I didn't set the .env file

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates), but **be aware of breaking changes** especially as it seems to be a **very old** version.

A better approach may be to use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md) - *node version manager* (or [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) if that is your operating system) to install and use an older - compatible version of node, e.g. v7.5.0.